# data.map is not a function

Tags: jquery, json

I'm bashing my head against an error I can't work out how to fix.  I have the following;

JSON

```
{"products":
[
    {
        "product_id" : "123",
        "product_data" : {
            "image_id" : "1234",
            "text" : "foo",
            "link" : "bar",
            "image_url" : "baz"
        }
    },{
        "product_id" : "456",
        "product_data" : {
            "image_id" : "1234",
            "text" : "foo",
            "link" : "bar",
            "image_url" : "baz"
        }
    }
]}
```

and the following jQuery

```
function getData(data) {
    this.productID = data.product_id;
    this.productData = data.product_data;
    this.imageID = data.product_data.image_id;
    this.text = data.product_data.text;
    this.link = data.product_data.link;
    this.imageUrl = data.product_data.image_url;
}

$.getJSON("json/products.json").done(function (data) {

    var allProducts = data.map(function (item) {
        return new getData(item);
    });
});
```

yet I'm getting an error that map.data is undefined as a function?  Looking at it I don't know what's not working as I've copied this to a new project from previously used code.  The only thing different is the JSON source.  The previous one didn't have the `{"products":` part before the [] brackets.  Is this what's throwing me off?

Comment: Please don't bash your head anymore - we will get through this...

Answer (score 336, accepted):

Objects, `{}` in JavaScript do not have the method `.map()`. It's only for [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), `[]`.

So in order for your code to work change `data.map()` to `data.products.map()` since `products` is an array which you can iterate upon.

Comment: iwow it works , thanks a lot i had same issues there was a row before the data

Answer (score 97):

The right way to iterate over objects is

```
Object.keys(someObject).map(function(item)...
Object.keys(someObject).forEach(function(item)...;

// ES way
Object.keys(data).map(item => {...});
Object.keys(data).forEach(item => {...});
```

[Read here for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: sometimes you might  be looking for values not keys

> Object.values(someObject).map(function(item)... //instead of keys

Comment: sometimes you might be looking for both Key and Values =>    Object.entries(someObject).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${value}`));

Answer (score 24):

In some cases (not in all), the **SIMPLEST** answer is to put **"data"** into a pair of square brackets (i.e. **[data]**) to change the items in the "data" into an array:

```
     $.getJSON("json/products.json").done(function (data) {

         var allProducts = [data].map(function (item) {
             return new getData(item);
         });

     });
```

Here, **[data]** is an array, and the **".map"** method can be used on it. **It works for me!** [image]

Or convert "data" into an array in the following way:

```
     let dataArr = Array.from(data);

     $.getJSON("json/products.json").done(function (dataArr) {

         var allProducts = dataArr.map(function (item) {
             return new getData(item);
         });

     });
```

**But the very question here is to get the "products" out of the "data":**

```
     data.products
```

**The "products" is an array.**

And then ".map" can be used:

```
     data.products.map
```

Comment: Doesn't this simply create a new array with only one data element - your original object? Why do you need to map that? `var data = {foo: 'bar'}; [data].map(function (item) { console.log(item); });`

Comment: Yes, it DOES simply create a new array with only one data element. There is nothing wrong with that. It's not that I who need to map. It's the specific project that needs to map. If it needs to map but your data is not an array, there'll be an error. Converting it to an array just changes its format, not its values, and that's just what the project needs.

Comment: I might be missing something. It seems to me that your example would do the same thing without the map: `$.getJSON("json/products.json").done(function (data) { var allProducts = new getData(data); });`

Comment: My original answer is very, very, very simple -- it's just to convert the data into an array, so that NOT ONLY will the "data.map is not a function" error DISAPPEAR, but more importantly, the .map method will also WORK to produce correct results. Nothing else.

Comment: "EpicVoyage" -- the problem is here is that you don't understand the question. The original question is "data.map is not a function", and please go to the top of the page and take a look at it. It's not MY project. I repeat: IT IS NOT MY PROJECT. It's how to fix the "data.map is not a function" ERROR.

Comment: @WilliamHou Let me explain the problem here with an analogy. OP has a lockbox which he needs help opening but only has a hammer that doesn't work. Instead of providing him with the key, you are suggesting he put the lockbox in a wooden box and then smash the wooden box with the hammer. Yes, he has now used the hammer but he still has the original problem -- a locked lockbox.

Comment: @Moataz Elmasry -- OMG. It's just an option! Nobody says it's the one and only answer. And I said "It works for me!", didn't I? It's very, very simple. If you understand the mechanism of it, you wouldn't even bother here.  God.

Comment: This is a nonsensical solution, and **objectively incorrect** in the context of the question. The answer is to use `data.products.map`, not to wrap `data` in an array.  Your answer causes the entire `data` object to be passed into `getData`, which clearly expects one of the elements from `data.products` as its input, **not** the entire data object. Your answer will cause the program to blow up when a line like `this.imageID = data.product_data.image_id;` is reached. Even if this weren't the case, layering an arbitrary object in an array just so `map` is available is still nonsensical.

Comment: @meagar -- You can do or say whatever you want, it worked for me. And obviously it works for somebody else too. It's not mandatory. It's just an option when nothing else works.

Comment: It "works" for some people in that it suppresses a specific error message, which is all some people want to do, but again, **it is objectively wrong**. You've accused your critics of not understanding the question, but your answer blows up the OP's code. It doesn't work in any meaningful way that will actually solve a real problem somebody has. In this specific case, it's wrong. In the general case, if you're invoking map on something that isn't an array, the answer is **don't do that**. Just use the object. Wrapping it in an array so you can use `map` on it is a completely pointless exercise.

Comment: @meagar -- You are right.

Answer (score 5):

`data` is not an array, it is an object with an array of products so iterate over `data.products`

```
var allProducts = data.products.map(function (item) {
    return new getData(item);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to map an object you can use Lodash. Just make sure it's installed via NPM or Yarn and import it.

With Lodash:

Lodash provides a function `_.mapValues` to map the values and preserve the keys.

```
_.mapValues({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }, function (v) { return v * 3; });

// => { one: 3, two: 6, three: 9 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**data** needs to be Json object, to do so please make sure the follow:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Now you can do something like:

```
data.map(function (...) {
            ...
        });
```

I hope this help some one

Answer (score 0):

You can always do the following:

```
const SomeCall = request.get(res => { 

const Store = []; 
Store.push(res.data);

Store.forEach(item => { DoSomethingNeat 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
.then(response => {
   if(response.status === 200)
   {
      this.usuarios = response.data.results.map(usuario => {
      return { name: usuario.name, url: usuario.url, captched: false } })
          }
    })
.catch( error => { console.log("Error al Cargar los Datos: " + error ) } )
```

Comment: Hello Fernando, and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is an English-only site. I have edited out the part of your answer that was *not* posted in English. Feel free to translate it and re-add it.

Answer (score -1):

There is an error on `$.map()` invocation, try this:

```
    function getData(data) {
        this.productID = data.product_id;
        this.productData = data.product_data;
        this.imageID = data.product_data.image_id;
        this.text = data.product_data.text;
        this.link = data.product_data.link;
        this.imageUrl = data.product_data.image_url;
    }

    $.getJSON("json.json?sdfsdfg").done(function (data) {

        var allPosts = $.map(data,function (item) {

            for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                new getData(item[i]);
            };

        });

    });
```

The error in your code was that you made `return` in your AJAX call, so it executed only one time.