# React Native type error: this.props.data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I am doing a single page app in react native. I want to display the fetch response in a list view. For accessing the response array i'm using map method but got the above error.The response from my server look like this

```js
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "type": "314",
    "status": "200",
    "message": "Successfully found the profile"
  },
  "neighbourProfile": [{
    "no_of_mutual_friends": "0",
    "username": "Amith Issac",
  },
  {
    "no_of_mutual_friends": "0",
    "username": "Liz",
  }]
}
```

How to use map method here?And my app.js is as follows

**app.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Neighbour from './src/components/Neighbour';

 class App extends Component {
    state = { neighbours: [] };
    componentWillMount(){
        const myArray = 
        {"requestHeader":
        {
            "personal_id": "122334",
            "type":"314"
        }
        }
        fetch(" https://xxxxx",{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
           body: JSON.stringify(myArray)
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) =>this.setState({neighbours: responseData}));

    }
    renderNeighbour(){
        return this.state.neighbours.map(neighbours =>
        <Neighbour key ={neighbours.username} neighbours={neighbours}/>
        );
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
      {this.renderNeighbour()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

What wrong am i doing?

Comment: are you using listview component ? and you want to map from neighbourProfile right ?

Comment: I want to list the response , for that i am using this map method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, you have to use `responseData.neighbourProfile` to make it work:

```js
.then((responseData) =>this.setState({neighbours: responseData.neighbourProfile}));
```

Since you only take `neighbourProfile` into account from your response data.

Comment: Okay and inside the render method i can use it as such right?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803168/data-map-is-not-a-function), you need to do the following to map over a Javascript `Object` (like a Python dictionary).

```
Object.keys(someObject).map(function(item)...
Object.keys(someObject).forEach(function(item)...;

// ES way
Object.keys(data).map(item => {...});
Object.keys(data).forEach(item => {...});
```

This is because only `Array`s have a `map` method in Javascript; `Object`s do not have this method.

Comment: So can you please explain how it will be in my case?

Answer (score 0):

responseData should be an array only..

something like this :-

```js
    responseData = [
      {
        "no_of_mutual_friends": "0",
        "username": "Amith Issac",
      },
      {
        "no_of_mutual_friends": "0",
        "username": "Liz",
      }
    ];
```

while the maps something like this.. usually we cannot use directly from this.state to map as it will become something else.. so, it's better if you assign a variable and get the value from the state..

```js
renderNeighbour(){
      
      //this one
      const { neighbours } = this.state;
      
      //or this one
      let neighbours = this.state.neighbours;
      
      return neighbours.map((data) =>
        <Neighbour key={data.username} neighbours={neighbours} />
      );
      
    }
```