# Data.map is not a fuction

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I'm trying to build a website for a school project. I setted up everything but i get the error "Data.map is not a function".
Actually i'm not an expert and i'm just trying to understand and copy the code that the teacher gave us (we did almost nothing in node.js).

I've built the server using node.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const process = require("process");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

let serverPort = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.set("port", serverPort);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/doctors', function(req,res){
    var config = require('./doctor.json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(config));
})

/* Start the server on port 3000 */
app.listen(serverPort, function() {
    console.log(`Your app is ready at port ${serverPort}`);
});
```

When i connect to the doctor page, i load a JSON file with all the doctors and i send it back to the client. Here is the JSON

```
[{
        "id": 0,
        "born": 2010,
        "tag": "cat",
        "name": "Eleanore"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "born": 2010,
        "tag": "dog",
        "name": "Katelin"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "born": 2012,
        "tag": "dog",
        "name": "Shea"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "born": 2011,
        "tag": "cat",
        "name": "Stephen"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "born": 2011,
        "tag": "cat",
        "name": "Rosanne"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "born": 2011,
        "tag": "cat",
        "name": "Alexa"
    }
]
```

Then i load the JSON and i would like to create dynamically items. Here is my client side code:

```
$.get('/doctors', function (data) {
    $("<div class='row' id='dottori' ></div>").appendTo(".team");

    data.map(addElement);
});

function addElement(doctor){
    console.log("Adding doctor");
    $("#dottori").append('<p> '+doctor.name+'</p>');
```

I keep getting this error, even if i stringify the json file (the same thing that my professor did), you can find the original code here: https://bitbucket.org/polimi-hyp-2017-10173412/polimi-hyp-2018-project/src/master/

Comment: `console.log(typeof data)` and verify that it is not a `string`.

Comment: Where should i test this? In my server or client?

Comment: Right before `data.map(addElement);`

Comment: @Taplar he has a nodejs service

Comment: Check if the response that you should map is not data.data, as sometimes Node wraps the response in a second "data" property.

Comment: Well I'm clearly not drinking enough coffee yet, -_-.  Yes, in your  `$.get()` method.

Comment: I get "string" which is what i've expected. Is it wrong? Searching on StackOverflow i found that map cannot be used over object, and that's why my professor stringify the json content, is it right?

Comment: You should probably parse it, not stringify it

Comment: Yes, you need to either parse it on the front end, or set the Content-Type: application/json on the response headers.  Setting the Content-Type will cause jQuery to auto parse it for you.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse`

Comment: By the way, the code you appended is using `fetch` no the `jquery.get` function

Comment: JSON.parse(), check here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: A quick google on setting the response header.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express

Comment: `JSON.parse(data).map(addElement);`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It works, thank you! Could you please explain me what was the problem? So the typical "procedure" is to stringify the JSON object from the server, and then parse it in my client? Sorry for the dumb questions, but they just throw us a bunch of code in 2 lessons and i'm really confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map the json **object**... `data` must be an object... Not a string.

It was received as a string... So you just have to parse it to an object.

Here, it is chained with the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method:

```
JSON.parse(data).map(addElement);
```

But you could have done (same thing):

```
var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
dataObj.map(addElement);
```

Remember the useful trick to check the type of a variable, mentionned by [taplar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586174/taplar):

```
console.log(typeof(variable-to-check));
```

[`typeof()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is a good debugging trick... And it is sometimes necessary to have it in some conditions to avoid errors (like if the script uses different sources).

;)

Answer (score 1):

Data received by `$.ajax()`, and any of it's wrapper methods, will receive the response as text.  If you want to process this response as an object parsed from the json, you will have to do one of a few things.

## You can parse the data yourself

```
var stuff = JSON.parse(data);
```

You can manually parse it yourself.

## You can make jQuery parse it explicitly

```
$.ajax({ url: ..., contentType: 'json' })
```

Providing the `contentType` parameter with the value of `json` will tell jQuery that the response should be json and it should auto parse it before giving it to a callback.

## You can make jQuery parse it implicitly

This is done by setting the `Content-Type: application/json` on the response.  When jQuery gets the response, it will inspect this header to try to intelligently guess what the response is and handle it.

According to this stack overflow post, [Proper way to return JSON using node or Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express), you can do so in node by...

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: This makes everything much clearer! I've solved my problem with map function parsing my data item. I read here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803168/data-map-is-not-a-function ) that map doesn't work with objects, but what .parse does is to create an object ( https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp ). I'm a bit confused

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map `map` is an array method, which arrays are objects.  Your json outer most token is `[]` so parsing it creates an array, so you can map it.  If the outer most token was `{}`, it would create an object that was not an array, and map doesn't work with plain objects, as stated in that linked post.  @MattiaSurricchio

Comment: I got it! Thank you, wish my prof was as clear as you