# TypeError: items.map is not a function , how to solve this error

Tags: json, reactjs

Everytime i run the code it shows the same error. Can anyone explain what is wrong with this code and how to rectify it? Items are in an array,you can check it in the url 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/8pyl4'.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../Stylesheet/bootstrap.min.css';



export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            isLoaded: false
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/8pyl4')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    items: json
                })
            });
    }
    render() {
        var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        return (
            <div>

                <ul>
                    {items.map(item => (
                        <li key="{item.ibn}">
                            Name: {item.name}  , Author: {item.author}
                        </li> 
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: json is an object, not an Array, hence it has no map method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [data.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803168/data-map-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting your *state[items]* to *json*, but it's an object, not an array! Go ahead and change:

```
this.setState({isLoaded: true, items: json});
```

to this:

```
this.setState({isLoaded: true, items: **json.items**});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/8pyl4')
            .then(res =>  this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    items: res.data.items
                })
            });
    }
```

Your `res.data` will be

```
{  
    "items":[  
        {  
            "ibn":123,
            "name":"Harry Potter",
            "author":"J K Rowling",
            "genre":"fantasy",
            "publisher":"bloomsbury",
            "ebook":"yes",
            "audiobook":"yes",
            "summary":"the chosen one and he who must not be named",
            "rating":"5/5",
            "price":"500"
        },
        {  
            "ibn":456,
            "name":"Artemis Fowl",
            "author":"Eoin Colfer",
            "genre":"fantasy",
            "publisher":"viking press",
            "ebook":"yes",
            "audiobook":"yes",
            "summary":"the rich child theif and fairies",
            "rating":"5/5",
            "price":"540"
        },
        {  
            "ibn":789,
            "name":"war and Peace",
            "author":"Leo Tolstoy",
            "genre":"drama",
            "publisher":"wordsworth",
            "ebook":"yes",
            "audiobook":"yes",
            "summary":"the russian epic on war and peace after it",
            "rating":"5/5",
            "price":"700"
        },
        {  
            "ibn":135,
            "name":"metamorphosis",
            "author":"Franz Kafka",
            "genre":"absurdist fiction",
            "publisher":"kurt wolff",
            "ebook":"yes",
            "audiobook":"no",
            "summary":"a salesman turns into an insect",
            "rating":"4/5",
            "price":"400"
        },
        {  
            "ibn":791,
            "name":"coraline",
            "author":"Neil Gaiman",
            "genre":"dark fantasy",
            "publisher":"harper collins",
            "ebook":"yes",
            "audiobook":"yes",
            "summary":"the most adventurous person ever",
            "rating":"4.5/5",
            "price":"560"
        }
    ]
}
```

now you need to get the items from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
{items.map(item => {
  <li key={item.ibn}>
    Name: {item.name}  , Author: {item.author}
  </li> 
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

All Json data are not array. Just check the data that you are trying to pass to the map function. Map functions take array data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).