# TypeError: posts.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Hi all I am new to react js and I am seeing error `posts.map is not a function` in the browser with the below code
I am importing this component in another file called `App.js`
please help m resolve this issue

```
import React, { useEffect,useState} from 'react';

import axios from 'axios'
import "./App.css";

function RedLipColor() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/redLipColor').then(res =>
    {
        console.log(res)
        setPosts(res.data)

    }).catch(err => { console.log(err)})
  })
  return (
    <div>
        <ul>(
            {posts.map(post => (
                <li key={post.id}>{post.title} </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
export default RedLipColor
```

Comment: You must ensure that the data being placed in your posts is array

Comment: what does res.data log in axios callback?

Comment: The error `posts.map is not a function` means that you are calling `map` on a non array object. Make sure `posts` is defined and is an array before calling `map` on it. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30803220/2873538)

Answer (score 0):

There are chances your API won't give data that time this will happen.

You should handle 3 cases 1. loading 2. data map 3. Empty state

Here is a minimal example:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

function RedLipColor() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('/redLipColor')
      .then(res => {
        setLoading(false);
        if (res.data) {
          setPosts(res.data);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {loading
        ? 'Loading'
        : posts &&
          posts.length && (
            <ul>
              {posts.map(post => (
                <li key={post.id}>{post.title} </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
      : No Data
    </div>
  );
}
export default RedLipColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do this, this is to check if `posts` array has data

```
{(posts && posts.length > 0) && posts.map(post => (
      <li key={post.id}>{post.title} </li>
))}
```