# e.map is not a function

Tags: json, reactjs, map-function

I am using map function to get "id" from multiple records of single JSON response.But I am having error like "e.map is not a function"

[image]

Comment: Can you please debug and show us what "e" is? Probably it is not array in this case, therefore does not have a map function.

Comment: probably `e` is not an array.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803168/data-map-is-not-a-function/30803220
If you can't find the problem after viewing this question, post your code

Answer (score 0):

map only works on variables which has been declared like following or having data like following

```
let e = [] //or
let e = [1,2,4,,5,6]
```

if you have you value in e as obj like

```
e = {} //or
e = {id: 1, name: 'example"}
```

You need to iterate it using 'for in'

```
for(var key in e){ console.log(e[key]) }
```

Make sure first what kind of data you have stored in e.

Comment: It Was an API response that I want to map....I simply parse it into JSOn by JSON.parse(<APi response >) and it worked.....