# data is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

I am getting this error at the console.  I have searched the forum and all the solutions aren't solving my problem. I am trying to retrieve the data and display on the table front end. The logging of data is successful. But am troubled iterating to display on a table. Below is the log output
[image]

```
import React, {  useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react'
import Layout from '../../core/Layout'
import axios from 'axios'
import {  getCookie, isAuth, signout } from '../../auth/helpers';


 export default class find extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Jobs: []
    };
  }
     getJobsData() {
      axios
        .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/projects`, {})
        .then(res => {
            const data = res.data
            console.log('List of jobs', data)
            const jobs = data.map((u =>
              <ul key={Math.random()}>
              <li>{u._id}</li>
              <li>{u.title}</li>
              <li>{u.addedBy}</li>
             
              </ul>
              ))
          this.setState({jobs: data})

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })

}
componentDidMount(){
    this.getJobsData()
}
render() {

    return (
      <Layout>
        <div>   
          <p>List of available jobs</p>
     {this.state.jobs}
        </div>
        </Layout>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: try `data.response.map(...`

Comment: @David "data.map is not a function" is the error and that exact question title already exists and is a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803168/data-map-is-not-a-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [data.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803168/data-map-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Not really. It doesnt work

Comment: Okay, I wanted to display the response into a table on the frontend

Comment: When i console log the response i see the exacts results object with array values

Comment: Screen from log above says its object with response key and value is array.

Comment: But when  i Loop through it to via the code above line 20, I can't get the results on the table

Comment: Try in browser console run this `console.log('List of jobs', {response: [1,2,3,4]})` and later this  `console.log('List of jobs', [1,2,3,4])`. Your screen match first console.log

Comment: it matches the first console.log above

Comment: Is there a way I can convert the response to be like the second log?

Comment: @ephantusokumu no, that other question *should* answer your question if you see how `data` is not an array in either and that the array is in a property on `data`. It is exactly the same reason the code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, {  useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react'
import Layout from '../../core/Layout'
import axios from 'axios'
import {  getCookie, isAuth, signout } from '../../auth/helpers';


 export default class find extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        jobs: []
    };
  }
     getJobsData() {
      axios
        .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/projects`, {})
        .then(res => {
            const data = res.data.response
            console.log('List of jobs', data)
            const jobs = data.map((u =>
              <ul key={Math.random()}>
              <li>{u._id}</li>
              <li>{u.title}</li>
              <li>{u.addedBy}</li>
             
              </ul>
              ))
          this.setState({jobs: data})

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })

}
componentDidMount(){
    this.getJobsData()
}
render() {

    return (
      <Layout>
        <div>   
          <p>List of available jobs</p>
     {this.state.jobs}
        </div>
        </Layout>
     )
  }
}
```

Your data is object with response key in it e.g.`{response: [1, 2, 3]}`. Try to change your data variable initialization to `const data = res.data.response`

Comment: This is the error message after doing so Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {active, _id, title, category, duration, durationSys, description, budget, addedBy, files, createdAt, updatedAt, __v}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Isn't key in state case sensitive? You have `Jobs: []` in your constructor and later you assiging to `this.state.jobs`. Try updated version.

Comment: @ephantusokumu and that is a completely different problem.