# map is not a function in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

When I did a console.log(response.data), it returned 2 datasets namely post and user:

```
 const [dbdata,setDBData] = useState([])

useEffect(async() => {
        const response = await Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/allpost', {withCredentials:true})
    setDBData(response.data)
    console.log(response.data)
    }, [])


{post: Array(2), user: Array(1)}
post: (2) [{…}, {…}]
user: [{…}]
```

So when I tried dbdata.post.map(), it says map() is a not function. What I am missing here? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that the data is empty from the server. Check console.log on the `response.data`.

Comment: there are data. {post: Array(2), user: Array(1)}

Comment: Please post the minimal code for people to help. from the snippet we are not sure which one threw error. `dbdata.post.map()` is not present in the code you shared.

Comment: Define your state like this -  const [dbdata,setDBData] = useState({post: [], user: []})

Comment: Thanks. So how do I solves this? Sorry am still not an experience a lot of scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Suran UK. I try later. Thanks again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [data.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803168/data-map-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

Initial state is an empty array `[]`

```
const [dbdata,setDBData] = useState([]);
```

so `dbdata.post` and/or `dbdata.user` are both undefined if you are attempting to render and map them on the initial render.

```
dbdata.post.map(...) // <-- throws error since dbdata.post undefined
```

## Solution

Provide correct initial state so the initial render has valid state to access and map.

```
const [dbdata,setDBData] = useState({ post: [], user: [] });
```