# ¿My error is 'data.map' or is my request api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

my code give me a error in `data.map`but i don't know how is the problem now.

```js
export const GetFilms = () => {


    const getPoster = async() =>{

    const url = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=********';
    const resp = await fetch( url );
    const data = await resp.json();

    const poster = data.map( Poster => {
          return {
              id: Poster.imdbID
          };
    })

    console.log(poster);
    }

    getPoster();

    return(
        <div></div>
    )
   
}


export default GetFilms;
```

the error that console my give is `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.map is not a function` .. thanks u for the time.

Comment: What is `data`? I assume it's not an array. According to their docs, `data` is an object, so it makes sense that `map` is not a function.

Comment: I would console.log(data) to debug it. It's likely that the response from the API is a dictionary that contains an array in one of its fields which is the one you want to run the map function on.

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30803168/2873538

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their example response, it looks like you just get back a plain object:

```js
const data = {"Title":"Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2","Year":"2017","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"05 May 2017","Runtime":"136 min","Genre":"Action, Adventure, Comedy, Sci-Fi","Director":"James Gunn","Writer":"James Gunn, Dan Abnett (based on the Marvel comics by), Andy Lanning (based on the Marvel comics by), Steve Englehart (Star-Lord created by), Steve Gan (Star-Lord created by), Jim Starlin (Gamora and Drax created by), Stan Lee (Groot created by), Larry Lieber (Groot created by), Jack Kirby (Groot created by), Bill Mantlo (Rocket Raccoon created by), Keith Giffen (Rocket Raccoon created by), Steve Gerber (Howard the Duck created by), Val Mayerik (Howard the Duck created by)","Actors":"Chris Pratt, Zoe Saldana, Dave Bautista, Vin Diesel","Plot":"The Guardians struggle to keep together as a team while dealing with their personal family issues, notably Star-Lord's encounter with his father the ambitious celestial being Ego.","Language":"English","Country":"USA","Awards":"Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 15 wins & 57 nominations.","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjM0NTc0NzItM2FlYS00YzEwLWE0YmUtNTA2ZWIzODc2OTgxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTgwNzIyNzg@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"7.6/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"85%"},{"Source":"Metacritic","Value":"67/100"}],"Metascore":"67","imdbRating":"7.6","imdbVotes":"573,212","imdbID":"tt3896198","Type":"movie","DVD":"N/A","BoxOffice":"$389,813,101","Production":"Marvel Studios, Walt Disney Pictures","Website":"N/A","Response":"True"}

const poster = {
    id: data.imdbID
};

console.log(poster);
```