# React: data.map() is not a function only after POST method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, components

Whenever I successfully update an user at UpdateUser component and I navigate back to my Home component, I get the **"Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function"**... When I navigate to other components and back to Home, this does not happen; it only occurs after updating any user. Video:
https://youtu.be/uUf9Yx91-jw

Home.js component:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import uniqid from "uniqid";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery(["user"], async () => {
    try {
      return await axios.get("/api/home").then((res) => res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

  const DisplayUser = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {data &&
          data.map((user) => {
            return (
              <div className="userCard" key={uniqid()}>
                <h2>Name: {user.name}</h2>
                <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
                <p>Id: {user.userid}</p>
                <button className="btn" onClick={() => deleteUser(user.userid)}>
                  Delete
                </button>

                <button
                  className="btn"
                  onClick={() => {
                    navigate(`/updateuser/${user.userid}`);
                  }}
                >
                  Update
                </button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const deleteUser = (id) => {
    axios.delete("/api/deleteuser", { data: { id: id } }).then((res) => {
      refetch();
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="userCardContainer">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <DisplayUser />
    </div>
  );
};
```

UpdateUser.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

export const UpdateUser = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [userid, setUserId] = useState("");

  const { data } = useQuery(["user"], () => {
    return axios.get(`/api/getuser/${params.userid}`).then((response) => {
      setName(response.data.name);
      setEmail(response.data.email);
      setUserId(response.data.userid);
      return response.data;
    });
  });
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      userid: userid,
    };
    axios.post("/api/updateuser", user).then((res) => console.log(res));
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="formContainer">
      <h1>{params.userid}</h1>
      <form className="addUserForm" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          className="formInput"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          value={name || ""}
        />
        <input
          className="formInput"
          type="text"
          value={email || ""}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          className="formInput"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Type new password"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input className="formInputBtn" type="submit"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I thought the issue was at UpdateUser component, yet once I reload the Home component, I see the updated user, so I think it must be related to the useQuery/axios GET request... I have already spent a couple of hours trying to figure this one out without any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error typically occurs when your trying to loop over an object using **map** function. Keep in mind that **map** is only available on **arrays**. Please refer to this answer here

[data.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30803220/4084160)

Here are 2 things you can do:

**1)** after updating the user do a **console.log(data)** before **return** keyword in Home.js component to see what's the value of **data** is

**2)** Keep in mind that instead of doing

```
   {data &&
      data.map}
```

you can simply do:

```
   { data?.map }
```

**Note:** If the value of data is an object after updating a user you need to add a condition such as only use **map** if data is an array, that should do it. Something like:

```
 { Array.isArray(data) && data?.map(...)    .....}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: { Array.isArray(data) && data?.map(...)    .....} fixed it! 
Though, if possible, I'd like to understand why...
1. If data was always an array, why was Array.isArray() needed in order to .map() it?
2. Why wasn't data?.map() successful by itself if data was indeed originally an array?
Thanks a lot really!

Comment: @Urias.Desarrollo I'm glad it fixed it! It's possible it was actually not an array which is why it was throwing that error.